# How to avoid showing Desktop when launching a JavaFX app from an other JavaFX app through ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX application in which a press on a button launches an other JavaFX application jar through ProcessBuilder.
Between the time I press the button and the time the other app starts (1-2 seconds), the first app disappears and reveals my desktop. I would like the user to never see the desktop. Does anyone here now a way to avoid having showing the Desktop during that time ? Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I really have no clue of what could solve my problem yet. I am new to UI development.

Comment: my guess is you just have to create a new stage. But  you say "Between the time I press the button and the time the other app starts (1-2 seconds), the first app disappears and reveals my desktop." Can you show a simplified version of this aproach. Then we can see where we can get from there?

Comment: Use a  [`PauseTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) that exits the firsts app after a two or three second delay.

Comment: You could create a splash screen for the second app. If done correctly it should be shown right when you start the app

Comment: Alternatively you could never close app 1 when app 2 is fully started check if app1 is running(via cmd) if so kill app 1 from cmd